# Trying to get PHP-FPM to work (Apache 2.4.33)

Tags: php, apache, lamp, apache2.4

- CentOS 7.5
- Apache 2.4.33
- PHP-FPM 7.2 (installed through the Remi repo)

So I'm trying to get this manually-compiled version of Apache running with PHP. Apache is all fine and dandy, but I'm not sure if I've installed things on the PHP side of things correctly or if the problem could be in my virtual host configuration. I'm going to try and add any relevant information:

PHP packages that are currently installed

```
mod_fcgid-2.3.9-15.el7.x86_64
php-7.2.7-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-cli-7.2.7-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-common-7.2.7-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-fpm-7.2.7-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-gd-7.2.7-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-json-7.2.7-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-mbstring-7.2.7-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-mysqlnd-7.2.7-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-opcache-7.2.7-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-pdo-7.2.7-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-xml-7.2.7-1.el7.remi.x86_64
php-xmlrpc-7.2.7-1.el7.remi.x86_64
```

Loaded modules

```
 access_compat_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 core_module (static)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 fcgid_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 http2_module (shared)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (static)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 so_module (static)
 ssl_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
```

User for Apache is httpd, group is www-data.

Below is the virtual host config (tried mashing things together based on some articles but the implementation wasn't entirely clear to me).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias www.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/httpdocs
  ErrorLog /var/www/domain.com/logs/error_log
  CustomLog /var/www/domain.com/logs/access_log combined

#  <LocationMatch "^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$">
#    ProxyPass fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/domain.com/httpdocs/$1
#  </LocationMatch>

  <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler php7-fcgi-webmin .php
    Action php7-fcgi-webmin /php7-fcgi-webmin
    Alias /php7-fcgi-webmin /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-webmin

    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
       Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
      SetHandler php7-fcgi-webmin
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>

  <Directory /var/www/domain.com/httpdocs>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -Includes
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Below is the FPM pool configuration for the site.

```
[domain_com]
user = webmin
group = www-data

listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.owner = webmin
listen.group = www-data

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 35

slowlog = /var/www/domain.com/logs/php_fpm_slow_log

php_flag[display_errors] = off
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/www/domain.com/logs/php_fpm_error_log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[memory_limit] =  64M
php_admin_value[open_basedir] = /var/www/domain.com/httpdocs
php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path]    = /var/lib/php/session
php_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir]  = /var/lib/php/wsdlcache
```

And that's where I'm at. When I visit a phpinfo page, it just prints the contents of the PHP file. There's not anything logged in Apache or PHP-FPM logs. Can someone tell me where I may have gone wrong? I have no problem with running through the whole process again if needed, or repairing things if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

With apache 2.4, best way is to use FPM and a SetHandler to proxy

```
SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
```

And you can read [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/) where the switch to FPM is explained.

You can remove the "php" package (which provides the mod_php which is uneeded)

Answer (score 0):

`[PHP-fpm With apache]`
`yum -y install httpd`
`systemctl start httpd.service`
`systemctl enable httpd.service`
`mkdir /etc/httpd/sites-available`
`mkdir /etc/httpd/sites-enabled`
`Add this line to the end of the file`
`vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
`IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf`
`vim /etc/httpd/sites-available/example.com.conf`
`<VirtualHost *:80>`
`ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1`
`</VirtualHost>`

`ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/example.com.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/example.com.conf`
`systemctl restart httpd.service`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).